# How to add survey monkey ios sdk inside my ios application?

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, surveymonkey

How to integrate Surveymonkey ios SDK inside my iOS App?

ViewController.h
I have tried following code in my project;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SurveyMonkeyiOSSDK/SurveyMonkeyiOSSDK.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) SMFeedbackViewController * feedbackController;

@end
ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
//static NSString *SAMPLE_SURVEY_HASH=@"e7bvbydjgchg6vyr2qyrzxkq";

 //#define SAMPLE_SURVEY_HASH  @"43w3IKqgkvJCvRLvKo8BXt_2FrXe_2BVheRgqp5w2R5TC2c_3D"
#define FEEDBACK_QUESTION_ID @"813797519"
#define FEEDBACK_FIVE_STARS_ROW_ID @"9082377273"
#define FEEDBACK_FOUR_STARS_ROW_ID @"9082377274"
#define SAMPLE_APP @"survey_sample"
#define SURVEY_HASH @"LBQK27G"
#define APP_ID @"DH9K6DY"
@interface ViewController () <SMFeedbackDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *takeSurveyButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;


//#define SAMPLE_SURVEY_HASH e7bvbydjgchg6vyr2qyrzxkq;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _feedbackController = [[SMFeedbackViewController alloc] initWithSurvey:SURVEY_HASH];
    _feedbackController.delegate = self;
    [_feedbackController scheduleInterceptFromViewController:self withAppTitle:@"survey_sample"];
 [_feedbackController presentFromViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (IBAction)didTapTakeSurvey:(id)sender {

}

- (void)respondentDidEndSurvey:(SMRespondent *)respondent error:(NSError *) error {

    if (respondent != nil) {
        NSLog(@"val is %@",respondent);
        SMQuestionResponse * questionResponse = respondent.questionResponses[0];
        NSLog(@"val new  is %@",questionResponse.questionID);
        NSString * questionID = questionResponse.questionID;
        if ([questionID isEqualToString:FEEDBACK_QUESTION_ID]) {
            SMAnswerResponse * answerResponse = questionResponse.answers[0];
            NSString * rowID = answerResponse.rowID;
            if ([rowID isEqualToString:FEEDBACK_FIVE_STARS_ROW_ID] || [rowID isEqualToString:FEEDBACK_FOUR_STARS_ROW_ID]) {
                [self showAlertWithBody:NSLocalizedString(@"Please rate us in the app store!", @"") hasRateButton:YES];
            }
            else {
                [self showAlertWithBody:NSLocalizedString(@"We'll address the issues you encountered as quickly as possible!", @"") hasRateButton:NO];
            }
        }
    }
   else {
       NSLog(@"error is %@",error);
   }

}

#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSString *appStoreURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@?mt=8", APP_ID];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appStoreURL]];
    }
}

- (void) showAlertWithBody:(NSString *)body hasRateButton:(BOOL)hasRateButton {
    UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Thanks for your feedback!", @"Heading for feedback prompt")
                                                     message:body
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Title of cancel button on app store rating prompt")
                                           otherButtonTitles: nil];
    if (hasRateButton) {
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Rate Us", @"Title of rate us button on app store rating prompt")];
    }
    [alert show];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Still I am not able to customize the code provided in GitHub. Please help if you have already implemented it in your iOS app.

Comment: FEEDBACK_QUESTION_ID @"813797519"
#define FEEDBACK_FIVE_STARS_ROW_ID @"9082377273"
#define FEEDBACK_FOUR_STARS_ROW_ID @"9082377274"
#define SAMPLE_APP @"survey_sample"
#define SURVEY_HASH @"LBQK27G" 
#define APP_ID @"DH9K6DY" ......from where to get the above keys ,I am not finding any steps.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies Swati & Horizon_Net -- the SurveyMonkey iOS SDK has not been officially released yet -- it's currently only available in a private beta. I'm the developer for the Android and iOS SDKs and would love to get your feedback. So, if you'd like to get in the beta, fill out [this form.](https://surveymonkey.wufoo.com/forms/k1qq7e6o0h1ijz0/)

We'll update this thread when the SDK has been publicly released, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Hi @bliken don't know if you're still on this project but I can't seem to get my iOS app to build on a simulator with the SDK, it only builds into my iPhone, and archives for production, I'm on an M1 mac and the simulator is running iOS 15.
Here's the error ...Pods/surveymonkey-ios-sdk/SurveyMonkeyiOSSDK.framework/SurveyMonkeyiOSSDK(SMRespondent.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '...Pods/surveymonkey-ios-sdk/SurveyMonkeyiOSSDK.framework/SurveyMonkeyiOSSDK' for architecture arm64